# Find the area of the region outside $r=4−3\sin \theta$ but inside $r=5\sin \theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

How will I do this? Will I get the points of intersection and integrate one by one?

Find the area of the region outside $r=4−3\sin \theta$ but inside $r=5\sin \theta$.

Comment: Hint: You should first visualize the regions.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!!Try putting your equations here-https://www.desmos.com/calculator and then proceed...best of luck!!

Comment: @MrYouMath got it. tried cutting a part of the circle to get the area of the arcs on the side and arc of the limacon intersecting inside. subtracted from the area of the circle. Done.

Answer (score 2):

It can be verified that in $[0,2\pi]$  the inequality
$$\rho_1(\theta):=4-3\sin(\theta)\leq \rho_2(\theta):=5\sin(\theta)$$
is verified in $[\theta_1,\theta_2]=[\pi/6,5\pi/6]$.

[image]

Thus by using the given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Integral_calculus_.28area.29),
$$\mbox{Area}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\rho_2^2(\theta) d \theta-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\rho_1^2(\theta) d \theta\\
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\left((25-9)\sin^2(\theta)-16+24\sin(\theta)\right)d \theta.
$$
The final result is $14\sqrt{3}-\frac{8\pi}{3}$.

Comment: I have seen the graph and it seems you've missed out 2 small arc sections on the side f the circle.

Comment: @D Frank I included a picture. The region is inside the circle and outside the cardioid. What am I missing?